# Convert []byte slice to []int slice

Tags: rest, go

What the code below does:

It gets to a given URL and responses with a plain text made of random numbers. At this moment the data is slice []byte, but I'd like to use those data so I think best solution would be to convert data to slice []int.

Here comes my code:

```
func getRandomInt(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    resp, err := http.Get("https://www.random.org/integers/?num=5&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("No response from request")
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body) // response body is []byte

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &bodyInt)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    //MY CONVERTER
    bodyInt := make([]int, len(body))
    for i, b := range body {
        bodyInt[i] = int(b)
    }

    js, err := json.Marshal(bodyInt)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    w.Write(js)
    fmt.Println("Endpoint Hit: getRandomInt")
}
```

I've tried to do a little bit of conversion myself. With given URL I should get 5 numbers in the range of 1 to 10. What I get after conversion are 10-11 numbers in the range of 10 to 60.

I did some tests and when the structure of body is like below, cnversion works fine.

```
body = []byte{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

So I think I read data from url response in a little different format, but have no idea how to solve that issue. Thanks.

Comment: byte slice is kind of a string, I think.

Comment: Okey. So i.e. I can iterate each value of body, convert that to string and later with `strconv.Atoi(s)` convert it to integer. I feel like it can work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `curl` that URL you can clearly see that the response is not JSON, so you shouldn't treat it as such.

```sh
curl 'https://www.random.org/integers/?num=5&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
```

```
5
10
4
4
2
```

It's just a new-line separated list of integers, so you should treat it as such.

```golang
resp, err := http.Get("https://www.random.org/integers/?num=5&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

lines := strings.Split(string(body), "\n")
numbers := []int{}
for i := range lines {
    line := strings.TrimSpace(lines[i])
    if line == "" {
        continue
    }

    num, err := strconv.Atoi(line)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    
    numbers = append(numbers, num)
}

// do something with numbers
```